# Variable in Nginx location path

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I need to achieve dynamic routing using single configuration in my revers proxy. How can I achieve following

```
location /<MY-VARIABLE>/docs {
        proxy_pass http://<MY-VARIABLE>_business:4000/api/v1/docs;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto http;
    }
```

Comment: Use the regex matching location: `location ~ ^/(?<varname>.*)/docs$ { proxy_pass http://$varname_business:4000/api/v1/docs; ... }`

Comment: @IvanShatsky $varname_business will be considered as single variable

Comment: Use curly brackets: `proxy_pass http://${varname}_business:4000/api/v1/docs;`